# How can I firm my pectorals back up?

Tags: chest, toning

I used to go to the gym regularly. Several years ago, for a combination of reasons, I stopped and the amount of exercise I was doing gradually declined to nothing.

I haven't returned to a gym, but have incorporated cycling into my daily life routine. During the week I cycle between 18 and 36 km most weekdays, depending on my schedule. I have been doing a combination of press-ups with various arm separation widths, sit-ups, and lifting of household objects, but with no strict routine.

I have a mostly vegetarian diet, but it is generally well balanced. I eat a lot, but my weight hasn't changed much over the past decade, even since stopping exercising. I seldom weigh myself, and have no scales, but whenever I do weigh myself it is usually pretty much the same weight. I'm not much of a fruit eater, but then again I haven't really got a taste for sweet things at all most of the time. I don't eat snacks regularly, and I don't drink much alcohol (but plenty of water).

Since starting exercising again I have seen all sorts of improvements, but my pectoral muscles, which were once fairly good, still seem flabby. I believe this is partly due to my posture, which is often criticised but causes me no pain or inconvenience, but not completely.

What can I do to firm up my pectoral muscles, preferably without any extra equipment or visits to a gym?

Comment: has your bodyfat gone up?

Comment: The question is way too broad. You need to mention your routine, diet, and any other piece of information to help us help you. Otherwise, I can just generally suggest some strength plans & a high-protein-high-calorie diet.

Comment: I've added a lot more detail now. Thanks for the feedback on what else to include, difficult to know on a SE site for a topic I'm not so knowledgeable about.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to do push ups ,if you say going to a gym is not a option you would like you can take the slowly but surely route of doing push ups.

And always try to do them in different positions ,if you want to firm them up try doing push ups with your hands on two chair and try to do as many as you can until you start feeling the burn.

Try something like:

- 5 series of Wide-grip push ups of 12-15 reps
- 5 series of Wide-grip push ups with your hands on the chairs and your feet on the floor of 12-15 reps
- 5 series of Wide-grip push ups with your hands on the floor and your feet on the chairs of 12-15 reps

But do not expect a 2 day miracle. You must do them and have at least 36 hours of rest before you do them again,depending of your body some people need more rest than others .

Answer (score 1):

You need to grow muscle in your pectorals and you are perfectly placed to follow a barbell program.

You should focus on doing Bench Press with a barbell (and/or Dumbbells)

Accessories to help you grow your chest could be:

- Incline Bench Press
- Decline Bench Press
- Weighted Dips

Without using weights or a gym you could follow a bodyweight routine. It will take longer to grow muscle than a traditional barbell program but will still work.

[Press-Up Progression](https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/exercises/pushup) (should be paired with a [Rowing Progression](https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/exercises/row))

[Dipping Progression](https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/exercises/dip) (should be paired with a [Pullup Progression](https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/exercises/pullup))